# Алгоритм поворота изображения

Tags: алгоритм

Предположим есть некоторый `bitmap` и его нужно повернуть на `45` градусов, с 90 кажется все более и менее понятно однако с 45 возникает проблема.

Comment: А что конкретно вы хотите знать ? С точки зрения геометрии при повороте любая точка, находившаяся в координатах [x,y] после поворота оказываться в координатах: `x'=x*cos-y*sin;  y'=x*sin+y*cos` где sin и cos синус и косинус угла (в радианах разумеется) поворота.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Если задаешь вопрос подобный, то задавай его конкретно. Например "Задача - повернуть битмап на N градусов. Есть ли функция, которая это делает, если нет - подскажите куда копать что бы самому написать такую функцию". А сейчас вопрос задан в очень топорной форме. Окроме того, если ты уже пробовал что-то, то нужно написать что пробовал.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте работать с Matrix а не с Canvas:

```
public static Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle){
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
      matrix.postRotate(angle);
      return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```